# Error response body is missing when exception is thrown @Around("@RequestMapping")

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

When I throw an exception around a function annotated with a `CustomAnnotation`, I get a response that looks like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "Jan 16, 2019 5:33:08 PM",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/path"
}
```

But when I do this around `@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)`, I receive a `401` status without a response body. Why is the response body missing and how do I work around this?

This is what the code looks like:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class AnnotationProcessor {
    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
//    @Around("@annotation(path.to.my.CustomAnnotation)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

My objective is to validate incoming requests based on the annotations specified for the controller method.

If someone could suggest a solution/a better way to accomplish the same, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use ResponseEntity instead of throwing a status exception

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint call){
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
}
```

You would be able to handle other HttpStatus on that ResponseEntity object, too.